# What is this bo staff form, possibly from Tang Soo Do?

Tags: forms, identification, bo-staff, tang-soo-do

I studied Chun Kuk Do (formerly Chuck Norris Tang Soo Do) in the 1990s in Kentucky. One of the forms that we were required to learn (I think for my green or brown belt) was a staff form. I don't know if it was actually part of the normal Chun Kuk Do or Tang Soo Do curriculum because my teacher liked to add forms and techniques from other styles. I remember the name being something like "Muhammed Basto Ana Isa". The form was at least largely done with a mixed grip (right hand underhand, left hand overhand). We would start out in *Jun Bi*, the ready stance with legs shoulder-width part, and the staff held about waist level with the arms straight. We would then twirl the staff with the right hand to being tucked under the right armpit vertically, and bow before returning to the ready stance. I don't remember exactly how it starts, but there's an early sequence (referred to as Sequence A in the written instructions. I think there was a Sequence B as well although I don't remember the details) involving a horizontal strike with the right side at shoulder-height followed by a strike with the other side, also horizontal at shoulder-height, then a downward strike and a reversed upward strike with the other side, followed by that first horizontal strike. That sequence was repeated several times in the form. The only other bits I remember is that at one point, we did a two-handed upward block followed by a two-handed low block, at one point we did a [figure-8 spin](https://blackbeltwiki.com/bo-staff-how-to-do-a-figure-eight) for two rotations (of course, sliding the hands together in the center), and I think there was a part where we slid the left hand closer to the end of the staff and did a low movement as if to hook a leg, followed by a thrust.

Oof... this looks ugly watching myself, but I quickly filmed the beginning twirl and bow, and an example of Sequence A

### Opening

https://youtu.be/LpKaTvatr_A

### Sequence A

https://youtu.be/RJXTa9iszRY

I've looked at [*Bong Hyung Cho Dan*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Jo9CQ7pJVQ), but it doesn't match my memories. The [UFAF Bo Form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=585zkKi1Uls) looks more complicated than what we learned (which would make sense for it being required for a third degree black belt) although I can see the "Sequence A" I mentioned above in it.

Comment: Was it this one? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBiJtYsn-LQ

Comment: That's Bong Hyung Cho Dan

Comment: bong hyung e bu? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_D9_ytPV6D0 or e dan? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOk3mMmJTI0

Comment: I'm afraid not. That "Sequence A" was a big part of it, repeated several times, including at least once where it was delivered during a pivot to the left (which would match the direction of the first forehand strike).

Comment: The opening itself doesn't help much, as different styles will often change the opening stances of some katas (with Tang Soo Do and TKD being especially known for "adapting" Japanese kata). However, your "sequence A" is very similar to that found in [Chatan Yara no Kon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V18qaG_BMcs), where it's done 4-5 times (including one with a pivot). I've seen variations of this kata that include a figure 8 spin at some point, and there is also a large sweeping motion performed by holding the bo from one of its ends. Does Chatan Yara no Kon look familiar to you?

Comment: @Dungarth: It is not the same form, but there are definitely some matching bits. Quite honestly, I have a growing suspicion that one of the teachers at our school invented this form just for our local school so that we would have weapons forms to test on to improve the "cool factor". Next time I'm at the family home, I'm going to do another trawl of the bookshelves to see if I can find my book of testing material.

Comment: As a further note, I reached out to the Chun Kuk Do organization and they do not recognize the form from my description or remembered name. They believe my instructor may have brought it in from another style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my book of materials from Virgil Davis's school:

> Weapons - Bo Staff Kata #1
>
> MOHAMMED BASTONE ANA ISA
>
> **SET 1:** V-stance, BO in left hand, Bring BO into cup of right hand, left arm is horizontal with palm down, now come to under arm set motion by rotating the BO 1/2 revolution.
>
> Turn body left and rotate the BO upward and grasp it with your left hand, step out with your right foot to straddle leg stance and low two-handed block - KIAI Pause two seconds, drop right foot back to forward stance, execute a two-handed high block, drop down to right knee and side strike to opponent's knee, stand up reverse side strike, downward strike, upward strike, and side strike.
>
> **SET 2:** Overhead reverse low block in a one-legged stance (right leg is up) as you turn 90° to left, pause one second, look left at 90°, step back with your right leg into a forward stance and do an upward strike, side strike, reverse side strike, and downward strike.
>
> **SET 3:** Step through with your right leg and look over your left shoulder, turn 180 and execute an overhead side strike, step through with right leg to forward stance and do three (3) figure-8 revolutions, step back with right leg and do a downward strike, drop to right knee and overhead low side strike, stand up reverse side strike (full hip). and side strike (full hip).
>
> **SET 4:** Look 90° right, jump into a cross stance, left leg behind. At the same time, do an overhead low reverse strike, bring the BO right hand up into a vertical position, pivot and spin toward your left 270° into a left leg out forward stance and do an outside vertical block, pivot (right) both feet 90° and do another vertical block.
>
> **SET 5:** (Left 90°) lift your left leg up into a one legged stance and do a side strike, step down with left foot in front and do a low sweeping motion into a set with the right knee up, step forward with right leg and do a high thrust.
>
> Turn 180° to the left rear and do as first half of SET 5. SET 6: Look left 90°, step back with right leg into forward stance, do a downward strike, upward strike, side strike, step forward right leg and middle thrust - KIAI
>
> Turn 180° to left rear and side strike, step forward with right foot and do an overhead low block, step back (right), do another overhead (left) low block, step forward again and middle thrust - KIAI
>
> **SET 7:** Turn 180° to left rear, do a side strike, reverse side strike, downward strike, upward strike, and side strike.
>
> **SET 8:** Look left 90°, step forward with right foot and pivot into a forward stance facing 90° left. Do same exact moves as SET 1.
>
> **SET 9:** Step through with your right leg and look over your left shoulder, pivot into a forward stance. Do same exact moves as SETS 1 and 8.
>
> **SET 10:** Step through with right leg and reverse low side strike, pivot both feet left 90 and side strike, reverse, down, up, and side strike - KIAI
>
> Return to ready, back to horse, and salutation, bow and set.

[Photographed page](https://photos.app.goo.gl/9pKXWM7Sguv3UXMZ8)

Answer (score 2):

Mohammad bastone anaisa. I grew up in afaf which was an off shoot from ufaf (chuck Norris’s association). This Bo kata was taught as a testing kata for 4th brown and then later for First degree black belt. I can not find a video anywhere on the internet. You are not crazy.

Comment: Thank you. That does sound like the right name, and I do remember the AFAF form 1 being listed in my book although I don't recall the details very well. Maybe, one day, I'll find the book at home, and get a chance to relearn it.

Comment: If you can provide any other documentation (maybe the list of movements or what you remember of it), I'll provide a further bounty.